# Aligning image over 2 background views

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

I have two background views with different colors. Both their own size.
Over these backgrounds, I need an image aligned on the left, over both other views.

how can i accomplish this?

```
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.rectangle1}>
               <Image 
        source={require('../assets/dame.png')}
        style = {styles.image}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rectangle2}>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Added sample image what to accomplish:

[image: Sample to show how it is wanted]

Comment: you can specify the width and height of the <view> components to get the desired layout. for the image, you can set position to `absolute` to specify a position on the left.

Comment: Indeed the absolute thingie did work. Thanks.
Do you also have tips to size the image for all devices and also have tips for quick loading? Sorry for this, i'm fairly new *blush*

Comment: i am not certain about the layout you are intending to build. perhaps, can you provide some illustration so that i can provide tips on that? e.g., do the rectangles fill up the entire screen? 50:50 ratio? horizontal or vertical?

Comment: Basicly i have 3 views with their own sizes. On those views i need to draw 3 images. 1 image is a wave line which is behind the logo. Logo overlaps 2 views and is centered at the right. Another image (centered at the left) is overlapping the 3 views and is also on the top of the waves . In the second view is also a box centered in the middle, showing some text. On top of the waves. The 3rd view is a menu view and is also on the top of the waves.
Hope this is a little more clear and else i need to draw something.. Sorry about that

Comment: Added image to illustrate what is needed

Comment: what is a menu view? and what about the box in yellow?

Comment: The dark blue on the bottom Will be the tabbar for menu.

Comment: And the yellow box is a text box showing Some information

Answer (score 0):

besides the use of `absolute` positioning, here is another tip to achieve a similar layout on most devices is the use of `Dimensions` and constants for the width and height of the devices that.

based on the information provided, here is how my design will look like:

```
////import { Dimensions } from react-native;

const { width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'magenta', height: deviceHeight }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: deviceWidth * 0.44,
            alignSelf: 'flex-start',
          }}
        >
          <Image 
            source={{ uri: 'https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=Alice' }}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            position: 'absolute',
            width: deviceWidth * 0.56,
            height: deviceWidth * 0.56,
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
            opacity: 0.7
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            width: deviceWidth * 0.7,
            height: deviceWidth * 0.1,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: deviceHeight * 0.8,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            opacity: 0.8,
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            width: deviceWidth,
            height: deviceWidth * 0.14,
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0,
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
            opacity: 0.8,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

i suggest you keep experimenting to find out which method works best for your application.

Comment: Thanks. I can’t get the logo the same size on all devices :( . In fact all the thingies are not all the same. Do you have tips for that? ☺️

Comment: what styles do you have on your logo? some height/width value or did you use the proposed deviceHeight/Width constants? the constants work better than the arbitrary values. and it all depends on your design layout.

Comment: I used/tried both. I do not get same results at all. Design is a thing to master i guess ☺️